# sorting or index in knowledgebase Allegro

Tags: sparql, allegrograph

I have a allegrograph knowledgebase that has hundreds of triples in it. Each triple contains subject predicate and object .I need to sort out/Index of objects based on predicate for example

Sub.  Pred.             Obj
d1.        hasName.   "abc"

Id5          hasName  "bac"

Id6.       hasName.    "cab"

If I search with "a" it should return "abc" only, that name starts with a in above example

If I search with "b" it should return "bac" only, that name starts with b

If I search with "c" it should return "cab" only, that name starts with c

Currently I have created anindex through allegro webview but it returns all statements wherever appears "a" in the record if I search with "a*" in string query. I want only the name that start with "a"
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL 1.1 has many operations:

```
SELECT * {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER(strstarts(?o, "a")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried  to execute this query in webview Allegro but it did not work.